# Why use server.join() in Embedded Jetty

Tags: java, multithreading, jetty, embedded-jetty

Using Embedded Jetty, I don't understand what `server.join()` does.

If I remove it, nothing happen, my server continue to work and keep serving requests.

What `server.join()` does? What happens if I remove it? In which case I would like to have it?

Here an example from the [official Jetty documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.35.v20201120/#jetty-helloworld):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int port = ExampleUtil.getPort(args, "jetty.http.port", 8080);
        Server server = new Server(port);
        server.setHandler(new HelloWorld());

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
```

I know the question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924874/embedded-jetty-why-to-use-join) but the accepted answer has `-6` upvotes so I thought it's worth asking it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call `server.start()` starts a new thread for the `Server`.

The call `server.join()` is to have the current thread to wait until the server is done before executing the next step on it's thread.

This is the normal [`java.lang.Thread.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) behavior.

In short, it makes the current thread wait for the conclusion of the thread it's asked to join.

If you had an action after `server.join()` you would see that it doesn't execute until the server thread has completed. (usually due to a graceful shutdown action).

Comment: Hi @JoakimErdfelt :) - That's awesome that you're the same person who put the comment with the most upvotes in the same question asked 7 years ago. Thanks a lot!